# Extract values from two dataframe columns in alternate fashion in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a datetime-indexed dataframe with 2 columns. I am trying to create a third column `df['eventv2'] = ...` containing values (circled in red) extracted from these 2 columns in an alternate fashion:

[image]

I tried to do some padding with `ffill()`, get the last non `nan` with `last_valid_index()`, all without success. I suspect I should use a function but I have no such advanced experience. I am able to achieve the desired result with a `for` loop iterating row by row, by overwriting a variable that records the last column position, but iterating is too slow and I would like to take advantage of dataframe operations.

Comment: The main problem here is that the value for the new column doesn't just depend on the value of other columns in the same row, nor does it just depend on some aggregate value over the entire column (like a maximum or sum). The value for each row in the new column depends on the values of other columns in an varying number of previous rows, in order - that basically implies some iterative approach will be needed. You best chances are probably finding the most efficient way to implement that iterator. Can you share the code you had, so people can suggest optimisations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flow of the process is to 1) delete NA lines at the row level, 2) create a list of column numbers to be retrieved. E.g., from the first column, [1,2,1,21,...] If it starts with 2, create [2,1,2,1,2...] 3) Merge that list into the original data frame; 4) Process it in a loop with 4) (if the value to be retrieved is NA, do not advance the counter value of [1,2,1,2...]

```
df.dropna(axis=0, how='all', inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df['eventv2'] = 0
condition = [1,2]*len(df)
# if 2 start
# condition = [2,1]*len(df)
df = pd.concat([df, pd.Series(condition)], axis=1)
global C
C = 0
for i in range(len(df)):
    if condition[C] == 1:
        if np.isnan(df.loc[i, 'buyv2']):
            df.loc[i,'eventv2'] = np.NaN
        else:
            df.loc[i,'eventv2'] = df.loc[i, 'buyv2']
            C += 1
    elif condition[C] == 2:
        if np.isnan(df.loc[i, 'sellv2']):
            df.loc[i,'eventv2'] = np.NaN
        else:
            df.loc[i,'eventv2'] = df.loc[i, 'sellv2']
            C += 1
df
    buyv2   sellv2  eventv2 0
0   -0.000160   NaN -0.000160   1
1   -3.504600   -3.504830   -3.504830   2
2   -0.000153   -0.000153   -0.000153   1
3   NaN 0.000140    0.000140    2
4   -1.178410   NaN -1.178410   1
5   -0.000291   NaN NaN 2
6   -9.676030   -9.676030   -9.676030   1
7   -2.729510   NaN -2.729510   2
8   NaN -0.000150   -0.000150   1
9   -7.571970   NaN -7.571970   2
10  NaN -0.000224   -0.000224   1
```

Comment: Solution works, thanks. In the interest of speed, I implemented a panda-based solution.